# How to hide Title and leave a sandwich (three stripes) in Navigation Draw?

Tags: android

I have a standard Navigation Drawer application designed by android studio.

I would like to remove the top panel and leave only three strips, please tell me options for how to do this?

[image]

Project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For hiding the Title in you java code after you have `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`You can add this line of code

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

For removing the options icon(3 dots on the right) you need to find the overriden `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method in your code. and remove the line where it inflates the menu.

```
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

So remove the above line and it won't create the options menu.

Can't say this is the perfect solution, if someone has better suggestions, do share.

Comment: Nothing changes at all  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

Comment: Can you confirm you set this in your MainActivity ```onCreate``` method,  after the line ```setSupportActionBar(toolbar)```

Comment: No idea why this won't work, it can be set inside fragments too ```((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);``` like so, but without this the only other solution i have is to edit the res files for each fragment and set ```android:label=" "```,(with a space) setting it as null or removing will default to activity label ...then app label etc.